# SICP Ex. 1.17 - "fast-multiply" slower than "multiply"?

Tags: scheme, lisp, multiplication, sicp, mit-scheme

The following function as introduction to this exercise illustrates multiplication defined in terms of addition. This is the simplest "easy to write down", recursive definition.

```lisp
(define (star a b)
  (if (= b 0)
      0
      (+ a (star a (- b 1)))))
```

First thing I did when I saw that, following previous exercises, is write an iterative form which doesn't blow the stack:

```lisp
(define (star a b)
  (star-iter a b 0))
(define (star-iter a counter sum)
  (if (= counter 0)
      sum
      (star-iter a (- counter 1) (+ a sum))))
```

Exercise 1.17 then encourages us to find an invariant so as to reduce the problem size, the idea being to get from O(n) to O(logn) number of steps (without, when that particular step is carried out, doing anything to update the result - all we do in that step is to reduce/transform the problem definition - that being what is meant by 'find an invariant') (see line 3 of the first code block below - nothing is being added to the result in that step).

For the fast version, the question says we should use the functions `halve` and `double` and seems to imply these would be available as machine operations (constant time?).  I've implemented the "fast" version just spoofing those functions as follows:

```lisp
(define (fast-star a b)
  (cond ((or (= b 0) (= a 0)) 0)
        ((even? a)      (fast-star (/ a 2) (* 2 b)))
        (else      (+ a (fast-star a       (- b 1))))))
```

And the same thing in iterative form (i.e. O(1) space):

(note how `+ a` on line 4 above just moves to the accumulator, end of line 6 below, to get this in tail position)

```lisp
(define (fast-star b)
  (fast-star-iter a b 0))
(define (fast-star-iter a b sum)
  (cond ((or (= a 0) (= b 0)) sum)
        ((even? a) (fast-star-iter (/ a 2) (* 2 b) sum))
        (else      (fast-star-iter a       (- b 1) (+ a sum)))))
```

So this is kind of a "what's the point" question - these functions are slower than the first two given above. The first of these four functions blows the stack so it's not useful. But the second doesn't. That one is *faster* than any of these two "fast" versions under my testing.

Am I missing anything here?  Curious if there's a way to implement `halve` and `double` so they actually give the log(n) result being suggested here. There must be otherwise there would have been no sense in the question.

Note that the order of a & b matters a lot if they are different sizes - like multiplying 2, 100 times or 100, 2 times, the first being 100 steps, the latter 2 steps. That would be something to add to this function later. But curious about `halve` and `double` to start with.

Comment: Apart from the problems pointed out in the answers, note that `halve` and `double` are single-bit shifts, for the fixnum->fixnum case.  I expect almost all CPUs have such operations.

Comment: `(fast-star (/ a 2) (* 2 b))` was supposed to be `(* 2 (fast-star (/ a 2) b))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a subtle bug in your code, that's why it's slow. This should fix it, for versions 3 and 4:

```
(define (fast-star a b)
  (cond ((or (= b 0) (= a 0)) 0)
        ((even? b) (fast-star (* 2 a) (/ b 2.0)))
        (else (+ a (fast-star a (- b 1))))))

(define (fast-star-iter a b sum)
  (cond ((or (= a 0) (= b 0)) sum)
        ((even? b) (fast-star-iter (* 2 a) (/ b 2.0) sum))
        (else (fast-star-iter a (- b 1) (+ a sum)))))
```

The idea is to keep adding `a` and *decreasing* `b` at each iteration, but depending on the condition sometimes you were decreasing `b` and sometimes you were doubling it! Also notice that I'm dividing `b` by `2.0` to get rid of exact arithmetic, which is slower.

Of course, you could do things the other way around: adding `b` and decreasing `a` - the important part is to be *consistent* about it, halving the problem on one parameter and doubling the other parameter, and the one that was doubled is the one that we need to add to the final result.

Comment: what's the difference between dividing by 2 and by 2.0? What happens with the arithmetic behind this difference?

Comment: @salvarico when we divide by `2`, we're doing integer division and Scheme will represent the value as a fraction, an exact value, which will be slower to compute. When we divide by `2.0`, we're doing floating point division and Scheme will represent the value as a decimal number, an inexact value which will be faster to compute.

Comment: Ohh. I understand this. But since we are only dividing by 2 when b is even, it will always get an integer as a result. However, I'm still wondering what difference will it make to make integer division vs doing a division with a decimal number (but also exact since it's an integer). Is there a difference in terms of memory and time?

Comment: Yes, there will be a difference. When you divide by `2.0` you no longer get an integer as a result! Even if it's an exact operation. For example: `(/ 10 2.0)` will return `5.0`, not `5`. A floating value is a different data type, without the overhead of a rational, which is what you get when you do a division between integers - even if it's an exact integer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue is that `b` is being both decremented and doubled, i.e., `b` should be halved not `a`.  Currently 2 * 100 would become 1 * 200 and require 200 decrements instead of 100.  Whereas if should become 4 * 50 and then 8 * 25, ...

Also if we decrement an odd number the result will be even so the next step will halve the value of `b`.  I.e, at least half the iterations will halve the value of `b`

E.g. if `b` < 1048576 (2^20) then the number steps should be less than 40.  Generally the number of iterations is less than (* 2 (log b 2)).

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that instead of using the formula

```
a*n = a+a*(n-1)
```

you should use the formula

```
a*n = a*(n/2)+a*(n/2)
```

and take care about the cases when `n` is `even` and n is `odd`.  Applying this will give you `O(log n)` complexity instead of `O(n)`.

Comment: this is the answer.